# Passing A Reference Into A Boost Bind Class C++

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to modify a boost asio example so that I can pass a reference to some 'shared' memory (the application has two threads, 1 for reading/serving and 1 for writing/gathering data)

This is the original class
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server/connection.cpp

This is my class instance

```
void connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred, CSharedMemory &oSharedMemory)
{
  if (!e)
  {
    boost::tribool result;
    boost::tie(result, boost::tuples::ignore) = request_parser_.parse(request_, buffer_.data(), buffer_.data() + bytes_transferred);

   if (result)
   {
      reply_.status = reply::ok;
      reply_.headers.resize(2);
      reply_.headers[0].name = "Content-Length";
      reply_.headers[0].value = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(reply_.content.size());
      reply_.headers[1].name = "Content-Type";
      reply_.headers[1].value = "application/json";     
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_, reply_.to_buffers(),
          boost::bind(&connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else if (!result)
    {
      reply_ = reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_, reply_.to_buffers(),
          boost::bind(&connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
          boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
  }
  else if (e != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
    connection_manager_.stop(shared_from_this());
  }
}
```

When I add CSharedMemory &oSharedMemory to the function (and to the header definition) i start getting errors that I dont really understand.  Can someone please help

Here are the errors

```
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:75:37: error: ‘void (http::server::connection::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, CSharedMemory&)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
     typedef typename F::result_type type;
                                     ^~~~

/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp:1033:7: error: static assertion failed: ReadHandler type requirements not met
       BOOST_ASIO_READ_HANDLER_CHECK(ReadHandler, handler) type_check;


/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:1092:7: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (http::server::connection::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int, CSharedMemory&), boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<http::server::connection> >, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >) (const boost::system::error_code&, const long unsigned int&)’
```

How can I pass a reference to my data to this function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boost::ref or boost::cref to wrap the references:

```
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
      boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
        placeholders::error,
        placeholders::bytes_transferred,
        boost::ref(my_sharedMemory)
      ));
```

Better yet, don't use `bind`:

```
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
      [this,self=shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t xfr) {
           handle_read(ec, xfer, my_sharedMemory_);
      });
```

Remember to capture whatever `my_sharedMemory` is supposed to come from.